# Integration of Rightmove Real Time Data Feed (RTDF) asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

i am integrating rightmove real time data feed (rtdf) in my property site for listing my properties on rightmove website. i am using asp.net web api to post data on rightmove listing.
they have provide me with these SSL Files [.p12,.pem,.jks]. i have imported .p12 certificate in my local machine personal store and sending it in my http request
to rightmove test api link provide by rightmove.
i am getting the following error from server.
**The remote server returned an error: 403 forbidden.**

i checked my certificate loaded successfully in the request, below is my code

```
public static string PostData(string data, string url)
{
    String result = "";

    try 
    {
        byte[] bytebuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = bytebuffer.Length;
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        objRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0";
        objRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        objRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        objRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(CertificateHelper.GetRightmoveApiX509Certificate());

        using (Stream stream = objRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytebuffer, 0, bytebuffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            // Close and clean up the StreamReader
            streamReader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = "Exception: " + e.Message;
    }
    return result;
}
```

help me to get rid from 403 forbidden error.

Comment: this is url where i am sending request https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.
I have tested it and it's working fine in my case.

```
// Grab Certificate
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "CertificateName.p12",
    CertificatePasswordHere,
    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);


var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Clear();
httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(data);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: The main thing here, is that it's using the `p12` certificate, rather than the `pem` one. Rightmove will send through both (and another one). For some reason, the `pem` cert works with PHP, and the `p12` cert works with c#.. No idea why